# do included files in php use information from the files that included them?

Tags: php, include

Say I have a the following files

## Example 1

### functions.php

```
<?php
     session_start();
     function getSessionData(){
         ...
         // returns array
     }
?>
```

### index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("functions.php");
    $sessionData = getSessionData();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php print_r($sessionData); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the index.php includes functions.php. Because I have `session_start()` in index.php, does this mean it's automatically added in the functions.php (seeing as functions is included in index?)

Im not sure if im making this clear or not.

## Example 2

### config.php

```
<?php
    $url = "www.example.com";
?>
```

### functions.php

```
<?php
     include("config.php");
     function getSomething(){
         ...
         return $url
     }
?>
```

### index.php

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    include("functions.php");
    $some_var = getSomething();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?=$some_var;?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now both functions.php AND index.php include config.php...

But because config is already included in index.php...

does this mean it has to be included functions aswel?

I think I've just confused myself tbh:)

Comment: You can include a file as many times as you want, AS LONG as it doesn't define any functions/objects. If you double-include a function-defining file, you'll get a "Cannot redeclare whatever()" fatal error. Simple variables, blocks of output, etc... are all fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can think of includes as simply pasting the code in the file where the include statement is.

In example 2, you don't need to include config again in index, as it has already been included in functions (or vice versa) - what you're actually doing there is running the code in config.php twice (which can be prevented by using `include_once` for example).

The same goes for `session_start()` in example 1. When index is loaded the following happens:

1. `session_start`
2. include functions.php

   1. `session_start` (not needed now)
   2. `function getSessionData() {..}`
3. (back to index) - call `getSessionData()`

Also, in your second example, you won't be able to access `$url` in that function without calling `global $url` before it (inside the function).

Comment: so in the first example. i do NOT need to call session_start() again because its already called in index?